# After softkeyboard opens, the screen can't adjust itsef correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I read a lot of topic related to this item but none of them solved my problem. Here is the layout of my chat screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/chatPage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/speech_bg" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/chatHeader"
    layout="@layout/header_chat" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chatHeader" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatBottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/speech_text_bg"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/chatSendButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/chatSendButtonWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/chatSendButtonHeight"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chatEditText"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_send_btn_selector"
            android:onClick="ChatSendButtonClick" >

            <com.xxx.Utils.MyTextView
                xmlns:customtext="http://schemas.custom.com/android/customtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/chatSendText"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/chatSendTextSize" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chatEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/editTextHeight"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chatSendButton"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="5" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        xmlns:pulltorefresh="http://schemas.custom.com/android/pulltorefresh"
        android:id="@+id/chatList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chatBottomView"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0px"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        pulltorefresh:type="chat" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I added *AdjustPan* option to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.ChatActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

AdjustResize doesn't work in my implementation since there's not a scrollview in it, I guess.

What is the best way to resize/adjust my chat page when soft keyboard opens? As far as I see, there's no implementation for listening the keyboard in Android either. I only saw some samples related with global layoutlistener to understand the keyboard position but it didn't work well for me.

Why does adjustpan option hides my actionbar instead of only chat screen?

Comment: try android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" permission in the menifest

Comment: are you getting something on Logcat??

Comment: I didn't see any specific logs/errors on Logcat after adding your suggestion

Comment: are you using you own keyboard or system provided?

Comment: Do this: inside com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView disign add one more line android:layout_weight="1" and change android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" to android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" only...  After this please let me know

Comment: when you clicked the textview, system provided keyboard pops up. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.. it's not possible to use             android:layout_weight="1" option in RelativeLayout.

Comment: yes you are right.I forgot that you are RelativeLayout. Anyway have you changed the windowsSoftInputMode to adjustPan only

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change anything. I still cant see the actionbar

Comment: let me upvote your question. Lets see what will be the solution for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added to pulltorefreshlistview in chat.xml layout:

```
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

It solved everything. If the chat list view is scrollable in any kind of conditions, it doesn't need to listen the keyboard event to scroll the list view manually.

Hope it helps to anyone other than me either..